# How to automating task assignment via Python?

Tags: python, automation, workflow

I am facing a challenge in automating a workflow:

Assuming there are `m tasks` to be assigned to `n employees` based on the description of the task (**n < m**).

After assigning the tasks, there is a certain order of dependency between the tasks, for example, task `m1` needs to be processed based on the results of task `m2` being completed first.

Without knowing the order of dependency between these tasks, how can I automate the entire workflow?

I've find the `graph` algorithm can approach this problem, but I don't know how to do.

Can anyone suggest a method or algorithm(`python`) that can automate the entire workflow without knowing the order of dependency between the tasks?

I appreciate any suggestions or insights you may have. Thank you in advance.

#### The task data should be like:

| Task ID | Task Description | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | draw a apple | e1 |
| 2 | ... | e1 |
| 3 | ... | e3 |
| . | ... | e2 |
| . | ... | ... |
| n | ... | ... |

#### The task workflow may be like:

```
Task2 -> (Task1 、 Task3) -> Task4 -> Task5
```

Comment: Please, check [ask] and also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefect for that

writing for the  order  :
Task2 -> (Task1 、 Task3) -> Task4 -> Task5

you can chose to write for your requirement

```
    from prefect import flow, task
    
    @task
    def task1():
        return do_sth
    
    @task
    def task2():
        return do_sth
    
    
    @task
    def task3():
        return do_sth
    
    
    @task
    def task4():
        return do_sth
    
    
    @task
    def task5():
        return do_sth
    
    @flow
    def workflow():
        t2 = task2.submit()
        t1 = task1.submit(wait_for = [t2])
        t3 = task3.submit(wait_for = [t2])
        t4 = task4.submit(wait_for = [t1, t3])
        t5 = task5.submit(wait_for = [t4])


if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    workflow()
```